# How can ι create my own (custom) WordPress table/list?

Tags: plugins, forms, api, list, table

I don't know exactly how is the correct name, but i want to create my own table like the default wordpress table :

[image]

I wanted to ask, does the WordPress provide some API to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this but I did get into it a little recently. Take a look at this tutorial: http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/

Basically, you'll want to create a class that extends `WP_List_Table`:

```
class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
   // what your table is all about
}

$myListTable = new My__List_Table();
```

It is an involved process, but that tutorial seems pretty good. Good luck!

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i want! Thanks you! :D :D 
Although the WordPress itself [**does not recommend it**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table). Also, thank you so much for the tutorial! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for pointing that out... Well, hopefully it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already create your custom post type? Or were you trying to modify what appears on that page?

If you are trying to create your own post type then you need this function:  [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) Wordpress creates the screen you see above (admin-edit) automatically as part of this process.  You can customize what appears in the columns with manage_CPT_posts_custom_column and manage_CPT_posts_columns filters

Comment: Yes, i have already created my custom post type, but i want to create this table/list ( _How is it called in the terminology of WordPress ?_ ) **regardless** of custom post type. I want to do it and it contains my own fields irrespective of my custom post type. Actually, i want to create a submenu with a table view ( like WordPress table view ).
Thanks you.

Comment: I have also used this : [Custom List Table Columns](https://make.wordpress.org/docs/plugin-developer-handbook/10-plugin-components/custom-list-table-columns/), to add an extra column to the default table, but ι want to create from scratch an entire table so.

Comment: please provide the use example.  maybe you're looking for an options page?  We will need to know what you're doing to be able to help.

Comment: I just want to show in a nice way a table of data from the database. A typical table. And i thought ( because i want it for an WordPress add-on ), if i can make a same table like WordPress.